# Drag and Drop file upload with GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to implement a drag-and-drop file upload for my GWT app. I've tried

http://www.vectomatic.org/gwt/lib-gwt-file-test-latest/lib-gwt-file-test.html
http://map-notes.blogspot.com/2013/01/minimal-implementation-of-file-drag-and.html

However the demo itself does not work. What are my options for implementing this for my app without using any Flash solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the GWT Uplader -

http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-uploader/

> If the browser is capable of handling file uploads using a modern
>   HTML5 approach, the upload is handled using pure DOM elements and
>   Javascript events. In the case that the browser does not support the
>   modern approach (most notably IE 9 and earlier), the GWT Uploader
>   component instead transparently handles the uploads via the
>   Flash-based SWFUpload library.

I have no problems with it, and it doesn't appear to use flash with any modern browser due the HTML5 support.  Didn't take me to long to get it added myself and integrated as they have pretty good documentation.

Comment: I also use the gwt-uploader but when I want to upload multiple files, each file is uploaded in a single request. I didn´t find a way to upload multiple files in one request. How can I do this?